# accessing confusing elemental distribution in php array

Tags: php, arrays, key, associative-array

i'm attempting to access an item in a variable being passed to me from a black box.  When I use something like

```
var_dump($var)
```

to examine the contents of the  variable I am given something that looks like this

```
array(2) {
    'home' => array(6) {
        'label'=> string(4) "home"
        'title'=> string(15) "go to home page"
        'link' => string(45) "....com/store/"
        'first => bool(true)
        'last' => null
        'readonly' => null
    }
    'category2336' => array(6) {
        'label' => string(9) "the title"
        'link' => string(0) ""
        'title' => null
        'first' => null
        'last' => bool(true)
        'readonly' => null
    }
}
```

How do I access the second key in this array (map)?  Specifically the area labeled category2336.

Comment: Surely it's not too much to expect that one would read [the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php#language.types.array.syntax.accessing) before asking such a basic question?

Comment: Simply, `$var['category2336']`.

Comment: @RocketHazmat nay, I want that key, not the associated array.  the category itself will be variable -- it is unknowable and dynamically assigned from my end.

Comment: @easymoden00b: Will it always be the 2nd element?  You can use `array_keys($var)` to get an array of all the keys, then do `$keys[1]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If just want the *key*, then you can use `array_keys` to get an array of keys.

```
$keys = array_keys($var);
echo $keys[1];  // category2336
```

Comment: Thank you my pony icon'd broheim.